# Zip two lists and join their elements

Tags: python, list

I want to join this list:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
merged = ['1a', '2b', '3c']
```

Size of `list1` and `list2` always same.

Comment: Use a map when list1 and list2 are same. `map(lambda x,y: str(x)+y,list1,list2)`

Answer (score 14):

I'd prefer:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [''.join(map(str, i)) for i in zip(list1, list2)]
['1a', '2b', '3c']
>>>
```

Answer (score 11):

This should work for the case you've mentioned:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list3 = [str(x[0]) + x[1] for x in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the Solution

```
list1=[1, 2, 3]  
list2=['a', 'b', 'c']

[str(list1[i])+list2[i] for i in xrange(len(list1))]
```

This will give output : `['1a', '2b', '3c']`

Comment: I think it's more readable which more important than making it complex as there is no one definition of true pythonic code.

Comment: Tip to the others: use `range()` instead of `xrange()` if you're using Python 3

Comment: @KevinGuan better to use map instead of xrange.

Comment: @AkshayHazari: use `map` instead of `xrange`? how?

Comment: @KevinGuan Check my answer . `map(lambda x,y: str(x)+y,list1,list2) ` . I meant its better to use map instead of looping .

Answer (score 3):

```
map(lambda x,y: str(x)+y,list1,list2)
```

This will give output : `['1a', '2b', '3c']`

Comment: 1. `str(x)+y`: I think this isn't good, if the `list2` also is `int` as `str`. But OP didn't say this, so just a tip. 2. On Python 3 this will return a map object. So `list(the_code)` can works fine.

Comment: @KevinGuan list1 is clearly given as a list of ints and list2 is str. If that be the case use an additional str on y. I guess you don't love functional programming. And the question isn't tagged as python-3

Comment: Well, however I didn't say that I don't love functional programming. Just some tip.

Comment: @KevinGuan That is a wonderful tip. Really will help me immensely.  Thank you so very much .

Answer (score 2):

I'd prefer:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> [str(i) + str(j) for i, j in zip(list1, list2)]
['1a', '2b', '3c']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it functionally:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
merged = ['1a', '2b', '3c']


print(list(map("".join, zip(map(str,list1), list2))))
['1a', '2b', '3c']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']

merged_list = []
for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2):
    merged_list.append(str(l1) + l2)

merged = "".join(merged_list)
print(merged)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.